# Screenshare tool - record screen & webcam + share url

Tags: screencasting

Are there any alternatives to Loom or some other tool, which is able to record my screen with/without webcam as well and share the recording URL after the recording?

Loom does that, but on Linux, there is no installation possible, only usable through the Chrome plugin which does not allow recording video at a high resolution.

I am not looking for the screen recording only, but a way to instantly share the recording with my coworkers without any additional actions like uploading, etc.

Comment: Did you look into Open Broadcaster Software Studio?

Comment: @Hermann does it support instant upload and link share?

Comment: OBS Studio integrates seamlessly with services that do, e.g. YouTube Live. I actually had a hard time configuring it *not* to keep a recorded version of the live stream by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an alternative (which was released after posting my question).

[threadit.app (by Google)](https://threadit.app/)

It works via a Chrome extension and records screen + webcam in acceptable quality.

Loom works through an extension as well, but on Linux, video quality is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Try flameshot

https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot

Technically speaking, you can automate sharing anywhere (call custom command or script with shortcut). By default I think it only supports Imgur

Comment: `flameshot` is a great tool but I am looking for a screen recorder (video)

Comment: I was not aware it did not record video. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software and choose your favorite.

In the "Features" part both the recording and the sharing options are mentioned.

**Edit:** I didn't notice the webcam part, I don't think this feature is mentioned in the Wikipedia page. What I would do is combine software for the webcam with software for screen sharing. The *"Do one thing and do it well"* UNIX-philosophy usually gives the best results. This looks like a case where it's certainly true.